# Count word Frequency in data.frame of Yes and No

Tags: dataframe, cpu-word

I have a data.frame of the words "Yes" and "NO" looking as follow:

```
   Answer
1  YES
2  NO
3  YES
4  NO
5  YES 
6  YES
```

How can I count the Word frequency in this data.frame? Expected output looks as follow:

```
YES  NO
4    2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
df['Answer'].value_counts()
```

In case you'll have a situation with mixed cases answers (like in the first sentence of your question) use `df['Answer'].str.upper().value_counts()`

EDIT - I realized you didn't specify the lang, I assumed it python's `pandas`. if it is `r` dataframe then this should work `table(df)`